# Is it unlawful or not-done to field between bowler and sight screen?

Tags: rules, cricket, etiquette

In cricket, play usually stops temporarily when spectators or personnel walk or stand in front of the (live) sight screen. What about fielders? Should they move elsewhere on request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The role of the sight screen is to help the batter see the ball at the start of its flight, as it leaves the bowlers hand. If you think about the angles involved, it is mainly the upper portion of the sight screen that is used, so a fielder standing in front of it would not block this view.

The problem with spectators is typically not that they are in front of the sight screen, but that they are *moving* in front of the sight screen. Humans are very tuned in to movement visually, so having someone move in the line of sight of the batter is distracting. Under the laws of cricket, fielders are not permitted to move laterally as the bowler is running is (they can move towards or away from the batsmen under [Law 41.7, 41.8](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-41-the-fielder/)). Therefore, a fielder in front of the sight screen but stationary will not be distracting the batter. They probably wouldn't notice given that the Umpire and Bowler are also in the way.

Fielding directly in front of the sight screen would be a very poor field placement in any case.

Comment: "Neither long-on or long-off, but sort of floating between the two (And not quite deep enough): In most forms of cricket, an extremely unusual position; in the village game, however, an almost compulsory one, designed not so much to cover two distinct positions as to distract the batsman by having someone legitimately stand in front of the sightscreens - that is, where the sightscreens would usually be found in higher levels of the game. For this reason, if this fielder is sufficiently portly, his lilywhite-clad girth may well serve to assist the batsman, in which case he should be moved." :)

Comment: ^ From [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/blogs/content/story/647171.html).

Answer (score 5):

It is not unlawful to field between bowler and side screen. In fact there is a fielding position for that and it is called straight hit.

[image]

Usually the fielder is placed at an angle and I don't remember any captains using this fielding position. You can see all the [rules here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fielding_%28cricket%29).

Comment: Helpful picture. However, I do not know of any law that prevents a fielder being placed directly behind the wicketkeeper, and, indeed, the picture in your answer shows just such a position, _long stop_. If there is a regulation that makes such a restriction in one-day games could you please provide a reference to the details of it?

Comment: Read the link mentioned as rules here.  It is mentioned there.

Comment: I already have, but the Wikipedia page provided no citation for the assertion it makes, and therefore I don't see the basis for it.

Comment: @Spinner, Try again. Or search for the above words I posted in answer. You should get it. I have edited the answer with same content.

Comment: I know that the Wikipedia page makes that quoted claim. What I am querying is where the Wikipedia article gets that information from. I have not been able to find any reference to support it in either the Laws of Cricket or the ICC Playing Conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately not all details are available on the internet. Some things we have to learn from experience and by following cricket. This is just one of such instances. Let me know if you have ever seen a captain putting a fielder directly behind keeper. I remember Doulas Marillier(Mar 2002, Ind vs Zim) kept playing his famous scoop shot behind wicket keeper and captain could do nothing about it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7BwE_49f2tA

Comment: If there is no law or regulation that prohibits the captain from placing a fielder there, he/she is perfectly free to do so; whether he/she would want to do so is another matter (one reason might be to save 4 byes on a very fast outfield). Why would such a prohibition exist?

Comment: One possible reason, I can think of, is this. It is a wicket keeper's job to make sure the ball wont go past him. Keeping someone as backup behind him is absurd and hence no point in allowing that. In any case I haven't seen that happening at all. Having said that, if you feel that this is absolutely wrong and I should remove that comment from answer, I can do it. It is anyways not related to the original question at all.

Comment: I agree with you that it makes little sense having a fielder there, and that a captain would not normally put someone there - as you say, it is the keeper's job. It would make more sense to have the fielder at _third man_ or _fine-leg_. However, the Laws do not prevent captains making absurd decisions. In the absence of any reference to the Laws or Playing Conditions, I don't think the Wikipedia claim can be justified; however, as you say, all this is unrelated to the original question!

Comment: @ACB The Wikipedia quote is preceded by "In some one-day matches:". I think you may include that in the quote in your answer, because without it it doesn't seem to be true generally.

Comment: From [here](http://www.espncricinfo.com/blogs/content/story/647171.html): "Long stop: [...] It should be borne in mind that this fielder is often a chuckling simpleton with next to no concentration span, hence the high bye count. On the plus side, he has the stamina and arm of Forrest Gump." :)

Comment: @Gugg I doubt it applies even in one-day matches. As your (humorous) link suggests, _long stop_ appears to be a perfectly legitimate position, contrary to what Wikipedia claims.

Comment: If wiki were that wrong, I doubt it will stay there just like that. Someone would have already corrected it. And from the above link which talks about village cricket, I don't think you can generalize it to all one day matches.

Comment: @ACB I think Wikipedia may very well be right on this, but _without_ the preceding "In **some** one-day matches:" (note the "some") the quote seems false. So, Wikipedia may be right, but I doubt that this part of your answer is right.

Comment: Anyways edited it. But I think this has nothing to do with the question. That was just a gentle comment I added.

Comment: I suspect the origin of this confusion is that in ODI and T20 matches, there is a requirement that a certain number of players (the number varies in different circumstances) be not only inside 'the circle' but be in a subjectively defined 'catching position'. Having a player inside the circle, but directly behind the keeper would not be a catching position, and therefore not permitted if that player was being used as part of the quota. That's my best guess at the origin of the wiki quote, but there's certainly no specific prohibition, even though in practice it simply isn't used as a position.

Comment: I note that the Wikipedia quote in question was credited to an IP address rather than a user account, which may cast doubt on its reliability. @Bogdanovist That's a possibility; I'd have to look up the T20 regulations to confirm that.